# Can i have two different tiles-def.xml in one spring application ,one of which will be selected by condition

Tags: spring

I have two tiles-def e.g `tiles-def1.xml` and `tiles-def2.xml`.

Is it possible to pick one of the tile-def files using some sort of condition? For example, something like:

```
if (true) {
    choose tiles-def1.xml
} else {
    choose tiles-def2.xml
}
```

Comment: What is the condition that decides which file gets picked up?

Answer (score 0):

You can supply path to a definition file as an external property (to Spring java or xml configuration) based on environment application is running (if it is your use case). Java configuration example:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/path/to/properties/app.properties")
public class Application {

    @Autowired Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer() {
       TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer = new TilesConfigurer();
       tilesConfigurer.setDefinitions(environment.getProperty("pathToTilesFile"));
       return tilesConfigurer;
   }
   ....
}
```

If it is not a solution for you, please provide more details about your use case.